# Link 2 date fields Qlikview with different keys

Tags: sql, odbc, qlikview

I'm having trouble with Qlikview joining 2 dates. For example
[On the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACOHY.jpg), "Fecha RPL" should only link to same date in "Fecha SAP" They are downloaded from 2 different repositories (One is from SAP and another from an excel file).

The next [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JKUX.jpg) is to show the link between the files, not sure if will help understand the problem.

```
[SAP]:
LOAD

Date#(Date(Date#("Ejercicio/Período",'0MM.YYYY'),'MMM/YYYY'), 'MMM/YYYY') as "Fecha SAP",
    "Material Actual" as SKU,

FROM [\\ALICOPSRV2\Usuario$\Consultoria Interna\1. CI-Proyectos\11. DataBase\BD.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is SAP);
```

(The dates from sap are default: "002.2016") The other table code:

```
[RPL]:

LOAD
    Mes,
    Año,
    Date([FechaRPL], 'MMM/YYYY') as [Fecha RPL],
    Proyecto as [NOMBRE],
    "Monto RPL"
FROM [\\ALICOPSRV2\Usuario$\Consultoria Interna\1. CI-Proyectos\11. DataBase\BD.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is RPL);
```

Tried combining those fields on a single table but they connect through the key "Nombre" which is not present in [SAP], there is another excel file for "SKU" and "Nombre"

Answer (score 0):

Qlikview way of linking columns is by it's name. If those two columns have diferent names (Fecha RPL and Fecha SAP), Qlikview will never linked them.

Have you tried renaming one (or both) to ensure that the date columns have the same name?

Comment: They are not the same dates, for example one date shows 1/05/2016 and the other shows 20/05/2016 so I want to tell qlikview to link the month of may and the same with the other 11 months.

Comment: They are different, and that way they will never be linked. My suggestion would be to create on each table a new column (something like DateMonth on both of them) where you maintain only the year and the month part of the date. With the same name data will be linked and only as you need.